# Cant filter by category

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a filtering system by category. Whenever I try to click one of my category it always shows all the products but I want to show filter wise category list if I click Smart Phone it will only show me smartphone category products.

Here is my Models.Py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod   
    def get_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()


class Brand(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_brands():
        return Brand.objects.all()  

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='UNCATEGORIZED')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='NoBrand')
    price = models.FloatField()


    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products():
        return Product.objects.all()


    @staticmethod
    def get_products_by_category(category_id):
        if category_id:
            return Product.objects.filter(category=category_id)
        else:
            return Product.get_all_products()
```

Here Is my Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    products = None
    cats = Category.get_categories()
    brands = Brand.get_brands()

    categoryID = request.GET.get('category')

    if categoryID:
        products = Product.get_products_by_category(categoryID)
    else:
        products = Product.get_all_products()

    args = {
    'products':products,
    'cats': cats,
    'brands': brands
    }
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

Please help I am very confused here and also got stuck :(

Comment: How exactly do you *construct* the link to the view that filters by category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter in your views.py

```
if categoryID:
        
  products=Product.objects.filter(category__name=categoryID)
        
else:
        products = Product.get_all_products()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible answer for your problem. I have slightly modified your models.py and views.py file. Here's the result :

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'cat'
        verbose_name_plural = 'cats'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'brand'
        verbose_name_plural = 'brands'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='UNCATEGORIZED')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='NoBrand')
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

By creating a slug field that is unique, you are creating an index. Now let's look at the modified views.py file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import *

def product_list(request, cat_slug=None):
    cat = None
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    brand = None
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    if cat_slug:
        cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=cat_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=cat)
    
    args = {'products': products,
            'cats': cats,
            'cat': cat,
            'brands': brands
            }
    return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

We use the optional cat_slug parameter to optionally filter products by a given category. The idea is the same if you want to filter by Brand. Just don't forget to add a brand in your context.